# How to obtain Alexa Skill ID of any public Alexa Skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, home-assistant

I would like to trigger this Alexa Skill (which I did not build) https://www.amazon.co.uk/Kailash-Panwar-Personal-Affirmations/dp/B07SVY2RMT using the Alexa Media Player Home Assistant Integration (https://github.com/custom-components/alexa_media_player/wiki#triggering-a-skill). This requires the Skill ID. Could you please tell me how to obtain this Skill ID if I did not build this Skill?

Answer (score 2):

Only developers and owners have access to the skill id of their skills. The documentation you mention refers to your own skill id that you can get in the developer console.